# Capacitor and inductive coil in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, frequency, resonance, inductance

Does increase in $L$ of inductive coil with variable no. of turns or $C$ of capacitor with changeable capacitance increase frequency of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are asking this question in context of an L-C circuit. The reasonant frequency of an L-C circuit is given by the formula $$f = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$ where L is the inductance of the inductor and C is the capacitance of the capacitor.

Hence if any of these two values are changed the reasonant frequency of the circuit will be changed.

Comment: Would XC still be equal to XL if we changed L OR C separately? Would it still be at resonance? I think I am missing something!

Comment: The value of XC and XL will depend only on the values of  C and L and are independent of values of each other, if the reasonant frequency of the circuit is constant. And yes the circuit will be at reasonance if the frequency of applied e.m.f. matches with the reasonant frequency of  the circuit.

Comment: And yes XL=XC when the circuit is at reasonance

Comment: I mean if I increased C, for instance, XC will decrease (XL no change) so it will be no more at resonance because XC is less than XL

Comment: When you will increase C the reasonant frequency will change and hence XL will also change, and because XL IS NOT EQUAL TO XC the  circuit will no longer be at reasonable.

Comment: Not reasonable it's reasonance